# Foreign key to multiple other tables

Tags: django, database-design, database-schema

I am working on a content management system where a user can create a course for a student to go through.

So far my database has Course, Lesson, and Slide models and I want to connect my Slide model to Quiz, HTML, or Video:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name

class Lesson(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name

class Quiz(models.Model):
    points = models.IntegerField()
    # Link to quiz model

class HTML(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Video(models.Model):
    media_path = models.CharField(max_length=150)


class Slide(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slide_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=[("video", "Video"),("image", "Image"), ("text", "Text"), ("quiz", "Quiz")])
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.title



class QuizQuestions(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField()
    points = models.IntegerField()
```

Now my slide model could be 1 of 3 things:

1. Text (raw HTML)
2. Video
3. Test

How do I design my database slide model so it can either be a link to a Video, HTML, or Quiz?

My thoughts are:

1. I could create a module path in Slide and the path would be the
   connecting text would be the connection database and a foreign key
   to it
2. Somehow create a foreign key that connects to any of the other
   database tables

Let me know if you have any better ideas, I would like a solution that is scalable and I am open to new ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to implement this.

1. You can do this with a [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)
2. You can also do this with [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) by, for example, having a SlideContent model that each of the Text, HTML, and Video models derive from using [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).  Then the Slide can have a foreign key to the SlideContent model.